# Reopening a "ChartJS" chart in a new window (VS, C#, ChartJS)

Tags: c#, charts, chart.js

My Development environment is VS C# 2015

1. I have used four (4) "**chartjs**" charts in a single aspx file.
2. each chart in a separate four .ascx files (user controller).
3. Base on the user request, system will generate these 4 charts according to the customer filtration. This process takes time, because it takes required data from the DB.
4. Once it loaded to the single .aspx page, customer again need to **re open each chart in a separate new page.**

My question is, **can i reopen that same chart in to a separate new page without loading it data back from the Database**?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, all the instances of charts are can be accessed through the `Chart.instances` variable, you can use pass these value from one page to another page using several JS methods such as localStorage, keyValue pair etc.

Once you can access the `Chart.instances` variable in the other page, just loop through and create charts passing the using the `config` property of `Chart.instances`. See the below code where I have copied a chart using `Chart.instances`. Here I have created a fixed canvas placeholder for the chart, you can create that also dynamically or create four canvas placeholders in the other page beforehand. Fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/Lzo5g01n/7/

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
      borderWidth: 1
    }, {
      label: '# of Votes1',
      data: [17, 9, 13, 9, 20, 13],
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
      borderWidth: 1
    }, {
      label: '# of Votes2',
      data: [1, 6, 13, 12, 20, 5],
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});

function copyChart() {  
  Chart.helpers.each(Chart.instances, function(instance) {
    var ctxCopy = document.getElementById("myChartCopy").getContext('2d');
    new Chart(ctxCopy, instance.config);
  });
}
```